# How to use the express session's cookie's secure attribute for both http and https requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, express-session

I am developing a short term loan providing app.I have set the express-session's cookie secure attribute to false. When I am sending requests to my localhost, the header is HTTP. So the cookie getting set and as a result no error is occurring. However, when I am connecting to an outside payment gateway for doing transactions the header is setting as https and as a result the cookie is not able to set properly and throwing an error. So, how can I use the cookie attribute based on the http or https header condition

The code for my `app.js` is:

```
//database connection
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://sifat:12345@cluster0.xtknfmw.mongodb.net/test", function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Database Not Connected", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Database Connected")
    }
});
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

//App creation
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

//port setup
require('dotenv').config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

//Other usage for application
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.SESSION_SECRET));
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie : { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, secure: false},
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

//body parser configutation
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


//passport configuration
const passport = require('passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const localStrategy = require('passport-local');
const User = require('./models/user');
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


//router configuration
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
app.use('/user',userRoutes);
const loanRoutes = require('./routes/loan');
app.use('/loan',loanRoutes);
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
app.use('/admin',adminRoutes);
const paymentRoutes = require('./routes/payment');
app.use('/payment',paymentRoutes);

//caching configuration
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.set('Cache-Control','no-cache, private, no-store, must revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
});

//morgan configuration
const morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//Home page
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{res.render('home');})

//Server Start
app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);});
```

when I try to set cookie: {secure: true} then the output is

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2023-03-03T19:43:40.653Z,
     originalMaxAge: 86400000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false },
  passport: { user: 'Sifat Sikder' } }
```

when I try to set cookie: {secure: false} then the output is

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2023-03-03T19:43:40.653Z,
     originalMaxAge: 86400000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false }
 }
```

This is throwing the error

Comment: `secure: false` should work with both HTTP and HTTPS. `secure: true` *requires* HTTPS, but `secure: false` doesn't prohibit it.

Comment: with secure false my passport verification is not showing

Comment: Are you asking why the cookie you set for `http://localhost/` isn't being applied to a request to `https://payments.example.com/`?

Comment: YES,SIR.my cookie is getting lost when the payment gateway is redirecting me to the success url